# Override function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling base method using JavaScript prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560829/calling-base-method-using-javascript-prototype)

I want to inheritance object that will override function in javascript.

From the method I want to call to the base method.
In this case I inherit object `reader` from `Person` and now I want to override the function `getName` meaning that in reader first I want to call the function on `Person` and then to do some changes.

```
<script>
    /* Class Person. */
    function Person(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    Person.prototype.getName = function() {
        return this.name;
    }

    var reader = new Person('John Smith');
    reader.getName = function() {
        // call to base function of Person, is it possible?
        return('Hello reader');
    }
    alert(reader.getName());
</script>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since you are correctly overriding the function on the object itself and not on its prototype, you can still call the prototype function with your object.

```
reader.getName = function() {
    var baseName = Person.prototype.getName.call(this);
    ...
}
```

Comment: To have it more dynamically, use `Object.getPrototypeOf( this ).getName.call( this );` if ES5 is available.

Comment: I would use Person.prototype.getName.apply(this, arguments) so you don't lose any arguments. Unless you specifically don't want to pass the arguments.

Answer (score 41):

Vincent answered your direct question but here is what you would do if you would like to set up a true inheritance hierarchy where you can further extend `Reader`.

Create your person class:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.getName = function(){
    alert('Person getName called for ' + this.name);
    return this.name;
}
```

Create a Reader class as well:

```
function Reader(name) {
    // Calls the person constructor with `this` as its context
    Person.call(this, name);
}

// Make our prototype from Person.prototype so we inherit Person's methods
Reader.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

// Override Persons's getName
Reader.prototype.getName = function() {
    alert('READER getName called for ' + this.name);
    // Call the original version of getName that we overrode.
    Person.prototype.getName.call(this);
    return 'Something';
}
Reader.prototype.constructor = Reader;
```

And now we can repeat a similar process to extend Reader with say a VoraciousReader:

```
function VoraciousReader(name) {
    // Call the Reader constructor which will then call the Person constructor
    Reader.call(this, name);
}

// Inherit Reader's methods (which will also inherit Person's methods)
VoraciousReader.prototype = Object.create(Reader.prototype);
VoraciousReader.prototype.constructor = VoraciousReader;
 // define our own methods for VoraciousReader
//VoraciousReader.prototype.someMethod = ... etc.
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7BJNA/1/

Object.create: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

`Object.create(arg)` is creating a new object whose prototype is what was passed in as an argument.

**Edit**
Its been years since this original answer and now Javascript supports the `class` keyword which works as you'd expect if you're coming from language like Java or C++. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: this should have been the selected answer, it is clear and shows exactly how virtual inheritance in javascript functions using prototypes which is vague in many other answers

Comment: Wanted to solve a similar problem with an "ancient" version of JS and not using classes. The issue was a method defined as a property and not on the prototype. The .call() was the missing part of solving it without using some transpiler and ending up with messy code.

Answer (score 5):

I use this technique from John Resig to get inheritance and method overriding. It even lets you access to the overridden method by calling this._super().

http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it:

```
function Person(name) {
this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.getName = function(){
return this.name;
}

var reader = new Person('John Smith');
reader.oldGetName = reader.getName;
reader.getName = function() {
//call to base function of Person , is it possible ?
    return this.oldGetName();
}
alert(reader.getName());​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fXWfh/

Comment: Vincent's  answer seems to be much neater than this - probably a better way to go...