# Extending MomentJS to override toString() function

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to extend moment's toString function to return the date in a different format.

I.e. I want to create momentDate as below:

```
// Will return "Sat Dec 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+1100"
moment('2015-12-12').toString();

// Will return a custom format, e.g. "2015-12-12"
momentDate('2015-12-12').toString();
```

I've been trying with no success. I'm not sure if it's even possible because of how moment is written so I thought I would ask here.

Comment: You have to override the toString() to return what you want it to return

Comment: Try to understand [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) in `JavaScript`.

Comment: @piglovesx, moment is a function which is why I'm having a hard time! It's toString function definition can be found by looking at moment.prototype.constructor.fn.toString, I haven't had any success in trying to override this. I've tried to create a class and override this (similar to what is done in this comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/11542872/2248573) without much success. moment.toString() keeps getting modified too!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extend (with a new name) a static function in javascript without affecting the original?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34626229/how-do-i-extend-with-a-new-name-a-static-function-in-javascript-without-affect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question was answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34626333/2248573

Note: Solution works for v2.11.0.

```js
function extendedMoment() {
  var self = moment();
  
  self.__proto__ = extendedMoment.prototype;
  
  return self;
}

extendedMoment.prototype.__proto__ = moment.prototype;

extendedMoment.prototype.toString = function(){
  return this.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
}

document.write("Original: " + moment().toString());
document.write("<br/>");
document.write("Extended: " + extendedMoment().toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.0/moment.js"></script>
```