# How do I extend (with a new name) a static function in javascript without affecting the original?

Tags: javascript, oop, momentjs

I'm having trouble working out how to extend a static function (momentjs) so that I can override the methods, but without altering the original function.

To be clear I know how to extend an *instance* of moment to override the functions, but I want to extend the library directly so I get my own named instance of `moment` that I can use in the same way as momentjs.

As an example, I'd like to be able to do the following

```
extendedMoment().customFunction() //do something custom
extendedMoment().toString() //use customised toString() method
extendedMoment().format() //use the original momentjs method
```

I've tried a few options with copying the prototype etc, but editing the prototype of the new `extendedMoment` function seems to affect the original.

**Update**: answered below by @PatrickRoberts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging into [the source](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/c74a101d549b8b443b72d9a470839eaffea852c2/moment.js), you can't really directly extend the library because there are several scoped functions which are not exposed, and [`moment()`](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/c74a101d549b8b443b72d9a470839eaffea852c2/moment.js#L3518) is actually a [wrapper](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/c74a101d549b8b443b72d9a470839eaffea852c2/moment.js#L15) of a [wrapper](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/c74a101d549b8b443b72d9a470839eaffea852c2/moment.js#L1423) of a [wrapper](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/c74a101d549b8b443b72d9a470839eaffea852c2/moment.js#L1404) of a [wrapper](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/c74a101d549b8b443b72d9a470839eaffea852c2/moment.js#L1337) of the [constructor](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/c74a101d549b8b443b72d9a470839eaffea852c2/moment.js#L182). So here's about the best you can do by reusing the same extended prototype rather than assigning scoped functions inside the factory extension:

```js
function extendedMoment () {
  return Object.setPrototypeOf(moment(), extendedMoment.prototype);
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(extendedMoment.prototype, moment.prototype);
Object.setPrototypeOf(extendedMoment, moment);

extendedMoment.prototype.toString = function toString () {
  return this.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
};

console.log("Original: " + moment().toString());
console.log("Extended: " + extendedMoment().toString());
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The way this works is it replaces the instance's prototype (which is initially `Moment.prototype`) with `extendedMoment.prototype` inside the factory extension, reusing the same `toString` function for all instances of `extendedMoment`.

**EDIT**

I caught myself using the term "constructor" for `extendedMoment` so I corrected myself. It is actually a factory extension, since it is a static function as @ZakHenry pointed out. Apologies for the misnomer.

Comment: I tried this, see my updated question with snippet - I just get ` Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`

Comment: @ZakHenry my mistake, I forgot to make my constructor return the object.

Comment: Updated, no error now but the override does not seem to have take effect. I suspect that momentjs has something sneaky implemented to prevent constructor extension maybe?

Comment: Not to prevent, they just don't extend objects by using the prototype chain as javascript had intended. I'm working on an update.

Comment: awesome work, thanks a lot. I'm kinda glad to see that it was more complex than first glance. Also note for others that might see this - earlier versions of momentjs (I had 2.10.6, current is 2.11.0) don't work with this answer. I guess they changed the api somewhere. I'd better add a unit test to check this override always works.