# How to overide or change the javascript predefined function

Tags: javascript

How to rewrite or change the js default function. For example. Substr is a predefined function in javascript. I want to change it to return some other result.

Comment: yes, you can. have you tried anything?

Comment: Add part of the code that you have written and you the function that you want to override

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? 
This helps others to help you better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override function in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542192/override-function-in-javascript)

Comment: `String.prototype.substr = () => {console.log('i am overridden')}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are talking about prototypes:

```
String.prototype.show = function() {
  alert(this);
};

"Hello!".show(); // Hello!
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers and explanation.