# Javascript - Extend method in class

Tags: javascript

So I have cerated a class

```
function myClass()
{
}
```

With the method

```
myClass.prototype.theMethod=function()
{
}
```

Which is fine but I have a circumstance where I need to use this class but add extra commands to method instead of just overwriting the whole thing, if that is possible?

Comment: Can you be more precise ? Do you want to override this function for an instance ? For a subclass ?

Comment: No as I said i just want to add extra commands to this method even if that was just a single line to call another function.

Comment: Been discussed before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560829/calling-base-method-using-javascript-prototype and no, there's no `super` or `parent` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to overrid action in certain object, then you can do the following:

```
var myInstance = new myClass();

myInstance.theMethod = function () {
    // do additional stuff
    // now call parent method:
    return myClass.prototype.theMethod.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

For subclasses solution is almost the same, but you perform that not on instance, but on prototype of inherited "class".

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var theOldMethod = myClass.prototype.theMethod;
myClass.prototype.theMethod=function()
{
    //Do stuff here
    var result = theOldMethod.apply(this, arguments);
    //Or here
    return result;
}
```