# Angular js Controllers inheritance issue

Tags: angularjs

i just come across a sample code on Angular js Controllers inheritance from this url http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-controller-tutorial/

here is the code and i just do not understand one part.

```
<div ng-controller="BMWController">

    My name is {{ name }} and I am a {{ type }}

    <button ng-click="clickme()">Click Me</button> 

</div>


<script>
function CarController($scope) {

    $scope.name = 'Car';
    $scope.type = 'Car';

    $scope.clickme = function() {
        alert('This is parent controller "CarController" calling');
    }

}

function BMWController($scope, $injector) {

    $injector.invoke(CarController, this, {$scope: $scope});

    $scope.name = 'BMW';

}
</script>
```

1) i just do not understand this line of code `$injector.invoke(CarController, this, {$scope: $scope});`

2) which $scope is **BMWController** scope and which $scope is **CarController** scope ?

3) there is two scope {$scope: $scope} one in left and one in right which one is related with **BMWController & CarController scope ?**

4) why this keyword is used in invoke function ?

5) please help me to understand this line **$injector.invoke(CarController, this, {$scope: $scope});**  as much with easy explanation

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the [Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector), I think that these line means that you are:

1. `$injector.invoke(CarController...` : invoking the CarController function;
2. `... , this ...` : a reference to the invoker;
3. `...{$scope: $scope})` : the CarController has a dependency of $scope, so this line means that you are injecting th BmwController $scope into the CarController.

Besides all this, I really think that controller inheritance is a realy bad practice. If you need to share some logic between two controllers you should use Angular Services. They are singletons that exists during all lifecycle of your application and are meant to store logic or data, and, more importantly, make your controllers skin and elegant.

Take a look at this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/relferreira/2b5amcya/

**HTML:**

```
<div data-ng-app="app">

  <div data-ng-controller="MainController as mainVm">
    {{mainVm.name}}
  </div>

  <div data-ng-controller="DetailController as detailVm">
    {{detailVm.name}}
    {{detailVm.other}}
  </div>

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
    .controller('MainController', mainController);

mainController.$inject = ['UserService'];

function mainController(UserService){

    var vm = this;
  vm.name = UserService.getName();

}

angular.module('app')
    .controller('DetailController', detailController);

detailController.$inject = ['UserService'];

function detailController(UserService){

    var vm = this;
  vm.name = UserService.getName();
  vm.other = 'test';

}

angular.module('app')
    .factory('UserService', userService);

function userService(){
    var name = 'Renan'; 
  return{
    getName: getName
  }

  function getName(){
    return name;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Looking at the AngularJs source code we can find the invoke method:

```
function invoke(fn, self, locals, serviceName) {
      if (typeof locals === 'string') {
        serviceName = locals;
        locals = null;
      }

      var args = injectionArgs(fn, locals, serviceName);
      if (isArray(fn)) {
        fn = fn[fn.length - 1];
      }

      if (!isClass(fn)) {
        // http://jsperf.com/angularjs-invoke-apply-vs-switch
        // #5388
        return fn.apply(self, args);
      } else {
        args.unshift(null);
        return new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(fn, args))();
      }
    }
```

As you can see, it is using the [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method. As stated by Alex, this method needs a context and it is most used by inheritance and/or override methods. Take a look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/560952/1108979

it uses `call` method, that is similar to the `apply`.

Comment: how do i know service is singleton? can we write any code which prove service is singleton...looking for guidance. thanks

Comment: why we need to pass `this keyword` when we call `$injector.invoke()` give me idea

Comment: They are singleton by definition. Take a look at the doc(https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

Comment: Edited to try to explain the this keyword

Answer (score 2):

1) you run a function (`CarController`) and provide it arguments (`$scope`)

2) You pass your current scope (of `BMWController`) to the `CarController`, so they share scopes.

3) the line `{$scope: $scope}` creates an object with the key `$scope` and initializes it with the object `$scope`. Try to look at the first `$scope` just like any other object key, like `name` would be in `{name: 'Mou'}`

4) Invoke just runs the function with the given arguments: [$injector documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector)

You pass a function to the invoke function, but that function is without context. You need to tell it the where you want to run it. So by passing this which is the BMWController it runs it kind of inside the BMWController

Comment: why we need to pass `this keyword` when we call `$injector.invoke()` give me idea

Comment: Since you need the context of the invoke

Comment: You pass a function to the invoke function, but that function is without context. You need to tell it the `where` you want to run it. So by passing `this` which is the `BMWController` it runs it kind of `inside` the BMWController

Comment: we are basically calling car controller function dynamically but u said "it runs it kind of inside the BMWController" sorry not very clear because i am new in angular. will explain it in more detail with code example to clear this issue. thanks

Comment: You can ignore that bit, I wasn't very clear there. The this is so the injector will know where to run the function

Answer (score 2):

The line `$injector.invoke(CarController, this, {$scope: $scope});` calls the function `CarController` and passes the `BMWController`'s `$scope` as a parameter.

You can see it like:

```
function CarController($scope) {
    // ...    
}
function BMWController($scope, $injector) {
    CarController($scope);
    $scope.name = 'BMW';
}
```

and you can also pass other parameters like:

```
function CarController($scope, foo) {
  // ...

}

function BMWController($scope, $injector) {
    // ...
    $injector.invoke(CarController, this, {$scope: $scope, foo: bar});
}
```

So, instead of calling the controller function directly, you use the dependency injector to call it. The dependency injection is a design pattern that has multiple advantages as explained [here](http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/angularjs-dependency-injection-demystified/).

**Edit**

`this` an optional parameter to the invoke function `$injector.invoke(fn, [self], [locals]);` and is used to pass the current context: `BMWController` to the invoked controller function `CarController`.

In this example we define `this.foo` on the `BMWController` context and then we can access `foo` on the `CarController` context.

```
function CarController($http, $scope) {
  console.log(this.foo) // prints: bar
  // ....
}
function BMWController($scope, $injector) {
  this.foo = "bar";

  $injector.invoke(CarController, this, {  $scope: $scope });
  // ....
}
```

Comment: why we need to pass `this keyword` when we call `$injector.invoke()` give me idea

Comment: when we are passing this keyword to CarController function then where this reference will be store because CarController function has no argument for this keywor?

Comment: we pass it to the `$injector.invoke` function which takes care of initializing the `CarController` context with the `BMWController` context.