# Calling base method vs. prototype method

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

Why are some methods called from the base, while others are called from the prototype of an object?

For instance `String.fromCharCode()` is a base method as opposed to `String.prototype.charAt()` and `String.prototype.indexOf()` which are prototype methods.
Why are not all methods of built-in objects called in the same way?

Comment: You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635116/javascript-class-method-vs-class-prototype-method I think it answer to your question

Comment: `fromCharCode` is a factory method, it generates a new string, whereas the other methods work on an existing string.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure if this was answered in other threads. I searched for "javascript call base method vs prototype" but only came up results that didn't answer my question, like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560829/calling-base-method-using-javascript-prototype