# How can I call a base method of the constructor's prototype with the same name as a method in the class?

Tags: javascript

Given that I have:

```
var PersonClass = function () {
    function Person(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;

        this.name = function(){
            return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
        };

        this.setName = function(a,b){
            this.firstName = a;
            this.lastName = b;
            return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
        }
    }

    Person.prototype.name = function () {
        return "Proto_:"+this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    };

    Person.prototype.whoAreYou = function () {
        return "Hi i'm " + this.name();
    };

    Person.prototype.setName2 = function(a,b){
        this.firstName = a;
        this.lastName = b;
    };

    return Person;
}(); //PersonClass
```

And I create an instance:
Me = new PersonClass("Steve","Benj");
me.name() // returns Steve Benj.
What will call the prototype name method and return Proto_:Steve Benj ?

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560829/calling-base-method-using-javascript-prototype). I think what you are trying to do in this example is not possible, you may need to try a different approach.

Comment: `me.__proto__.name()` returns the proto-string but `__proto__` shoudn't be used - https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling base method using JavaScript prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560829/calling-base-method-using-javascript-prototype)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation between object and its prototype lies through `constructor` property. 
In your case the `counstructor` is `Person` function object. 
 `Person` has direct coupling with its `prototype`. 
 The last thing is to call a prototype method over a certain object to bind `this` keyword properly - and this can be achieved with [*Function.prototype.call()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) approach:

```
console.log(Me.constructor.prototype.name.call(Me));
```

The output will be:

```
Proto_:Steve Benj
```

---

The alternative approach is using [Object.getPrototypeOf(x)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) function which would give the same result:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Me).name.call(Me)
```

Comment: isn't that the same as `Me.constructor.prototype.name()`?

Comment: @ThomasAltmann, `Me.constructor.prototype.name()` will give `Proto_:undefined undefined`. See my explanation about `<function>.call(<object>)`

Comment: Oh right sorry, i just looked at the first few characters of the output and thought everything went thine, thanks

Comment: *"The relation between object and its prototype lies through `constructor` property:"* I think this is misleading. Every object has an internal `[[Prototype]]` property that references the object's prototype. The value of the object's `constructor` doesn't matter. E.g. `var foo = {bar: 42}; var baz = Object.create(foo);`. `Object.getPrototypeOf(baz) !== baz.constructor.prototype`.

Comment: @FelixKling, I meant the "evident" relation. I didn't want to push the OP to use `__proto__`(we know that it's not standard)

Comment: I see. Well, `Object.getPrototypeOf(x)` would be the more reliable, modern alternative.

Comment: @FelixKling, ok, I would call `.constructor.prototype` an "old - good - proven" approach. But, also added `Object.getPrototypeOf(x)` as an alternative

Answer (score 2):

The function defined in the Person constructor will overwrite/override the prototype definition that occurs below it, so there is no good way to invoke the prototyped function over the function defined in the constructor (see comments on your post for the "bad" way).

I would think about whether or not you want to use the same name for both of these functions, unless this is not your actual use case. I would say you would want to create a prototype function that is called protoName or something like that, if you want different behavior you should define different functions.

Answer (score 0):

The way you structure this, you invoked `PersonClass` function immediately after it's defined.

So `PersonClass === Person`.

So when you do `Me = new PersonClass("Steve","Benj");`, what you are really doing is `Me = new Person('Steve', 'Benj');`

So whenever you invoke those prototype methods, you are calling the prototype methods from `Person`.

You can verify this by doing

```
Me.constructor // => Person
```